# Implicit evidence for string to double

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

Let's say I want to divide anything implicitly convertible to `Double`:

```
def divide[T](a: T, b: T)(implicit ev: T => Double) = a / b
divide(1, 2)
// 0.5
```

However, (1) this wouldn't work with Strings out of box, and (2) attempt to provide implicit conversion like:

```
implicit def string2double(a: String): Double = a.toDouble
```

will fail:

```
cell3.sc:3: type mismatch;
 found   : a.type (with underlying type String)
 required: ?{def toDouble: ?}
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method augmentString in object Predef of type (x: String): scala.collection.StringOps
 and method string2double in class Helper of type (a: String): Double
 are possible conversion functions from a.type to ?{def toDouble: ?}
implicit def string2double(a: String): Double = a.toDouble
                                                ^
cell3.sc:3: value toDouble is not a member of String
implicit def string2double(a: String): Double = a.toDouble
                                                  ^
Compilation Failed
```

Why readily available conversion is not used and how to generalize `T` to strings as well?

Comment: Of course you know best for your specific use case, but I think it's worth pointing out that using implicit conversions can have unexpected pitfalls, especially when used on types as widely used as `Double` and `String`: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.12/scala/language$.html#implicitConversions:languageFeature.implicitConversions

Comment: Note for example that `toDouble` is not _really_ defined on `String`, but rather on an implicit class which is wrapped around `java.lang.String` through an implicit conversion: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.12/scala/collection/StringOps.html#toDouble:Double

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you know best for your specific use case, but I think it's worth pointing out that using implicit conversions can have unexpected pitfalls, especially when used on types as widely used as `Double` and `String`: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.12/scala/language$.html#implicitConversions:languageFeature.implicitConversions

Note for example that `toDouble` is not really defined on `String`, but rather on an implicit class which is wrapped around `java.lang.String` through an implicit conversion: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.12/scala/collection/StringOps.html#toDouble:Double

If you still think that using an implicit conversion is the best course of action for your use case, you can explicitly wrap the `String` in the `StringOps` wrapper to avoid the compiler some confusion. The following works:

```
def divide[T](a: T, b: T)(implicit ev: T => Double) = a / b

import scala.language.implicitConversions
implicit def string2double(a: String): Double = augmentString(a).toDouble

"1" / "2"
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/ZoLSKNOrSkqjZ03Nu0gGRQ/9).

As for the reason why your attempt doesn't work, my best guess (but take it with a grain of salt and validate it with someone who actually knows the Scala compiler) is that the compiler does an implicit conversion pass, during which implicit conversions are not yet available to the code, making "recursive implicit conversions" impossible.

Comment: The reason why it fails is because they are trying to define the conversion using `toDouble` but `toDouble` is added through the already existing `augmentString`, the problem is not the indirection _per se_ but rather that now `string2double` also allows to call `toDouble` on `String` because `Double.toDouble` also exists, thus creating the ambiguity. - BTW, even if you _"fixed"_ the example, the code now broke `String.toDouble` forever everywhere else in the code base and anyone importing it.

Comment: Yup, as mentioned, one should tread _very_ lightly when using implicit conversions. Personally, I would never do something akin to this. Thanks for the contribution!